# SMS using Bluetooth COM port connection guidance

Tags: sms, bluetooth, symbian, mobile-phones

Mobile phone AT&T guidance?

I connect my China/ and Nokia phone using Bluetooth COM PORT CONNECTION. It says COM at 5.

How can I use this connection to send and receive SMSes using C#? For example, are there some resources to consult, or how would some example code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using a bluetooth modem driver? If you are & its presenting the phone as a serial device on COM5 then you should be able to access it in the same was as any modem.

Try the [GSMComm](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm#gsmcomm) library, it also has a demo app you can use to test.

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick Google search, and I can't find a builtin API for exposing SMS capability via Bluetooth.  However, from searching the documentation on the Nokia site, it appears the Symbian C++ libraries have an [API for sending and receiving SMS](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Comms_Framework/index.html), as well as [libraries for interfacing with the bluetooth stack](http://library.forum.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/S60_5th_Edition_Cpp_Developers_Library/GUID-35228542-8C95-4849-A73F-2B4F082F0C44/sdk/doc_source/reference/reference-cpp/Bluetooth_Client_Library/index.html).  You'll need to install the Symbian C++ IDE and toolchain for building apps.  You can find information [here](http://www.forum.nokia.com/Technology_Topics/Development_Platforms/Symbian_C++/) on how to do that.